# Setting up multiple email aliases

Tags: windows-server-2003, exchange-2003

I have an user with the email:

```
lej@domain.com
```

I'd like to also have him recieve his emails on:

```
lj@domain.com
```

Note that it is the SAME (1) domain I'm talking about. Another example would be:

- ct@domain.com
- casper.thygesen@domain.com

I've tried adding the smtp adress in Email Adresses in AD, but it doesn't work.
Sending emails to lj@domain.com gives `Delivery Status Notification (Failure). Error: 550 550 Invalid recipient <lj@domain.com> (#5.1.1) (state 14).`

Current unsuccessful setup:

[image: Current setup in AD]

How do give an user multiple email aliases? I've googled for hours...

Comment: What delivery status failure message do you get?

Comment: I just updated the post - hope that is enough information

Comment: Weird - that's certainly the way to do it. Maybe leave it for a few minutes to replicate in AD and for RUS to do it's funky thang?

Comment: Do you get the failure both externally and internally?

Comment: I have waited hours :) Is there any way to force it? I can try restart the server tonight, but I'm skeptic that it will work.

Comment: RE: external vs internal: uuuuuh, it seems to work internally. How funny

Comment: Have you got an edge device you also have to put valid email addresses into so mail can pass through? Or something similar from your ISP?

Comment: Why yes, why yes I do. I'm an idiot. Thanks a lot!

Comment: There you go. Sometimes we all just need a gentle nudge in the right direction. The amount of times I have forgotten to enter email addresses into MessageLabs is unreal!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it works internally, check if you have some sort of edge device that only allows email addresses through that you enter into the device.

Your ISP may offer a similar service, or someone like MessageLabs also provide a similar service.

Comment: That is actually correct. We have messagelabs. Since it is external, I don't normally think of the service. I'm a doof. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It works for me having multiple addresses added just like you did. Have you redirected other domain to your Exchange server (i presume by aliases you mean different domains)?

You also need to add it to Recipient Policies in System Manager as per http://www.petri.co.il/configure_exchange_2000_2003_to_receive_email_for_other_domains.htm

Comment: No. Same domain. Just different alias e.g alias@domain.com.
There is only 1 domain attached to this exchange server.

Comment: Just go thru the link carefully. It has detailed steps. Should be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration is correct. However, it might take a while for these changes to be propagated. Patience is key (force update can probably be done as described in [kb319065](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319065)).